# How to ground PCB to chassis using mounting hole with vias in Kicad?

Tags: kicad, mounting-holes

Hi I have 4 layer board layered as follows.

1. Signal
2. Power
3. Ground
4. Signal

For the power and ground planes I have done zone fills...

I want to attach the PCB ground to my chassis using a screw. I initially just had a padded mounting hole, but someone suggested to fortify the hole with vias incase the screw somehow damages the plating and the connection no longer happens, but he's not sure how it works in KiCad.

I noticed there's a mounting_hole_pad_via footprint/component. And I used that. Is that enough, or do I need to do anything else special? The mounting hole is already attached to the ground fill. The surrounding holes are through-hole and marked as all copper layers.

I attached a picture...[image]

Pink is the ground pour, yellow is the power pour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not trying to solder to the pad, I would suggest that you modify the zone connection strategy in the footprint to be "solid" instead of "thermal relief".

Right now, you only have 4 of the 8 vias connecting to the ground plane on the ground layer.  Setting the footprint to "Solid" zone connection will connect all 8.

[image: Zone Connection Option]

Comment: Yeah I was wondering the same it's an internal layer so I wont be soldering anything. The ground fill is the hole board by the way. So there is other pads attached to it! But since it's all internal I can solid fill it.

Comment: Ok I think I got it, do solid only for that component right? I thought you mean the entire fill should be solid.

Comment: So like this? https://www.dropbox.com/s/uy0syv2g7ay75eh/Screen%20Shot%202020-11-16%20at%206.41.30%20PM.png?dl=0